# Only allow non unique combinations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want to disallow non-unique combinations of 5 columns in my interface table.
e.g. for the following columns:

```
:case_number, :client_name, :matter_name, :country, :engagement_code,
these rows should be allowed:
1,1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1,1

and these rows should not be allowed:
1,2,1,1,1
2,3,1,1,1
1,1,4,5,1
```

Comment: you sure that you do not have this reversed?  I would think the example at the bottom should be allowed and the top not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

In the model add:

```
validate :non_unique_combination?

def non_unique_combination?                                     
    if EvidenceImportInterface.count > 0 and 
       !(EvidenceImportInterface.exists?(:case_number => self.case_number,
                                        :client_name =>  self.client_name,
                                        :matter_name =>  self.matter_name,
                                        :country =>  self.country,
                                        :engagement_code =>  self.engagement_code))                                                 
        errors.add(:case_number,'Combination not valid')
    end 
end
```

Comment: It is not reverse. I wanted to disallow non-unique combinations. I just answered my question.

Comment: This was a real question. Only needed to be read carefully. I intended to dis-allow non-unique combinations as I was importing data from excel. I figured it out and posted the solution.